# Is there a way to tell if a join exits from a timeout or thread dying?

Tags: java

I have some code that talks to a api.  After the server runs for about a day, it freezes on the  call to stream.read;

I decided to put the code inside a thread. So if the thread timeouts it will return a null for the api's return value.  I could not find any code that tells if a join exit for a timeout or thread dying

```
String GetBitrexApiThread(String url) {

    cThread cRun=new cThread();
    cRun.url=url;
    cRun.run();
    try {
        // wait 10 seconds to make api call
        cRun.join(1000*30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // would like to return a null if thread timedout.
    return cRun.reply;    
}

// thread code
public class cThread extends Thread {
    String reply;
    String url;

    public void run() {
        try {

            URL myurl = new URL(url);
            System.out.println("Open connection");
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            System.out.println("Get input stream");
            InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("Create reader");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
            System.out.println("Creat buffer reader");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String inputLine;

            System.out.println("Read indata2");

            int t;
            while ((t= in.read()) != -1) {
                 // System.out.println("next read");
                 reply+=(char)t;;
                 // System.out.println(reply);
            }

            System.out.println("finish Read indata");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getting data from API server");
            reply=null;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `Thread#run != Thread#start`

Comment: Also, don't use `join()`. Use a `Future` or a `CountDownLatch` or some other concurrency primitive.

Comment: i suggest you use an ExecutorService as this designed to handle this sort of thing.  Only use raw Threads if you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread one = ...;
one.start();
one.join(5000);
if (one.isAlive()) {
  //clearly, the Thread is not dead
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will replace `run();` with `start();` otherwise your background task will run in the current thread.

The way to tell if the task is still running is to call `thread.isAlive();`  You also need to pass the result back in a thread sfae manner and handle an exceptions thrown.

As I commented an ExecutorService does all this for you.